# STL Object Splitting

Tags: objects

I have an object in STL format that I have imported into the Blender.
The Object is made of up several parts but in the editor mode it shows up as one set of polygons.

I have managed to use the Linked option in the Select menu to only have the desired parts in edit mode.

How can I make this a separate object from the original STL object ?

I just want to add different colors and textures to different parts of my object. But as it is Blender sees everything as one object .

I have attached an image where you can see the orange area are the linked parts in edit mode that I wish to separate from the original Green colored areas so that I can give them a different texture and color.

Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: You don't need to separate parts of objects to assign different materials https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh

Answer (score 3):

You can do this automatically by:

1. Select your mesh
2. Enter edit mode
3. Select All
4. Press <kbd>P</kbd> then choose `Separate by loose parts`

If you want to separate the selected parts then:

1. Select your mesh
2. Enter edit mode
3. Select the part of mesh you want to separate from the mesh
4. Press <kbd>P</kbd> then choose `Separate by Selection`

Comment: I've never used blender before.  How does one "enter edit mode"?  Is this not the default mode?  If I'm not in edit mode then is just a glorified model viewer until I flip a switch somewhere?  For anyone else that comes along and sees this in the future, there is a "dropdown" (or rather "dropup") in the tray at the bottom that starts as "Object mode".  That can be swapped to "Edit mode".

Comment: @claudekennilol enter edit mode with the tab button

Answer (score 0):

You do not necessarily need to separate parts of your object into multiple objects to be able to map different materials and textures to different parts of the same object. You can do this by defining the different materials and textures you wish to choose, then selecting sets of connected vertices and assigning the chosen material to each set.If you're going to be using the same set of vertices often, you may find it convenient to assign that particular set of vertices to a [vertex group](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/).